# Days between dates(Condition should be checked for dates overlapping)

Tags: excel

[image: Sample image]
[image: sample image 2]

[image: 3rd Image]

I need a formula to calculate days between two dates. Departure date 02/06/2018, arrival date 03/06/2018 hence my answer would be 2 days which includes departure date like wise if any dates are getting repeated in subsequent cells that should not be get counted, i.e., days calculation should be done for only distinct dates. Kindly suggest a formula to calculate this as per the image attached herewith. I have 3000 employees and more than 35k rows of data like this.

Sample image 2 shows 3days calculation done for oct18 and 3 days for nov18, which means i had calculated only 3days for the month oct though the travel was concluded by nov18 then i had considered the nov18 travelled dates into nov month's only.

Comment: What is the problem with the formula you are using now? What does your data look like?  Suggest you edit your question after you read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you with your problem.

Comment: Provide some sample data and how/where the results are viewed for this sample data. Be sure to include the desired results for the sample data input values. Is every date in there own cell? For one "employee" are the dates all on the same row (or column)? What about the day calculation, where does it live in relation to its input? Is there values other than dates in the data? Given `02/06/2018`, `04/06/2018` can `03/06/2018` appear? and so forth.

Comment: @Rsvraghavan, The solution I provided does not account for month boundaries (max days in month) as the sample data you provided does not show how you deal with travel that starts in one month and concludes on the following month.

Comment: @Rsvraghavan, As I explained, you need to provide an example of how the month boundary calculations are expected to work. Basically, if the date range is for 45 days and none of those days are previously accounted for, why are they limited to just the current month? Is the previous month's days calculated elsewhere? What does all this look like?

Comment: So this March 23, 2019 thru April 02, 2019 would be listed on two rows? One with an March 2019 month column and one with an April 2019 Month Column? I need to know if the month column is a date value displayed as MMM-yy or is it text?

Comment: I understand the row has the month cell, departure date cell and arrival date cell. You answered my question about the month cell. I am trying to ascertain whether the entire row (except the month cell) is repeated when the departure date and arrival date cross a month boundary; row with `| Mar 19 | 23/03/2019 | 02/04/19 |` and row with `| Apr 19 | 23/03/2019 | 02/04/19 |` so the same data repeated in multiple rows, one  for each month the travel range is a part of. I will continue this in 8 hours.

Comment: How are the travel days calculated for an employee who's travel spans a month boundary? Here is a three month span example: Travel Row `Dept Date = 28/4/2018` and `Arr Date = 2/6/2019` (total days 36). Is this travel listed three times, one row for each Month in the travel date's range with the Month values of `Apr-2018` (3 days), `May-2018` (31 days) and `Jun-2018` (2 days) being the only difference between these three rows? Also, 2007 is 1.5 years beyond End of Life, do you really need a formula which will work for this dead product?

Comment: @Rsvraghavan, Please provide some sample data for the month boundary scenario, including the desired results. Edit the question to include this clarified requirement with its sample data.

Comment: @Rsvraghavan, Please provide some sample data, NOT images, **actual data**, stripped down to just the essentials. Include the expected results with a description of how the results were arrived at from the SAMPLE DATA you need to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Exclude Previously Calculated Dates (criteria based) from Calculation

- The criteria matches a column's value in the formula row to this column's value for the considered dates.
- The considered dates are all those dates which precede the current row.
- Date ranges are inclusive

  - From yesterday to today is 2 days, unless yesterday was previously used to calculate days (for this criteria - Emp#), in which case this will be 1 day.

[image: sample]

**The Formula:**

`=DAYS(E4,MAX(IF(A4=$A$3:$A3,$E$3:$E3),D4))+IF(MAX(IF(A4=$A$3:$A3,$E$3:$E3))<D4,1,0)`

- Paste to G4
- CSE - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> this array formula.
- Copy drag down.

**Expanding Ranges**

- Both $A$3:$A3 and $E$3:$E3 are expanding ranges of the values that came before.
- The absolute row address `$3` and relative row address `3` should be the row above the formula start.
- Improve efficiency by restarting the formula (maybe every 1K-5K rows).

  - Requires data to be sorted by employee and then (the formula, as provided assumes) sorted by date for any give employee.
  - Always restart formula at the beginning of an employee.
  - The expanding range should reference the last record of the previous employee.
  - One edit to restart the formula: Change the absolute row references (in the restarted formula) to be the same as the existing relative row reference for each expanding range (there are four).

Sample Restart:

```
OLD =DAYS(E10,MAX(IF(A10=$A$3:$A9,$E$3:$E9),D10))+IF(MAX(IF(A10=$A$3:$A9,$E$3:$E9))<D10,1,0)
NEW =DAYS(E10,MAX(IF(A10=$A$9:$A9,$E$9:$E9),D10))+IF(MAX(IF(A10=$A$9:$A9,$E$9:$E9))<D10,1,0)
.                           ^   =    ^   =                         ^   =    ^   =
```

- In row 10, the `^` value becomes the `=` value at all 4 `^`.
- CSE and copy drag down the restarted formula.

**Explanation**

- Calculate the Days as End - Start and maybe add one.
- End is column `E`.
- Start is the max date seen for this employee.

  - The max considers the Start Date in column `D` as well as any PREVIOUS end dates for this employee (max does not consider the formula row's end date).
- Add one day if the max previous end days are less than this start date.

  - This means the start date has not yet been included in the count.
  - If a previous end date was the same as the start date, that calculation will have included the day in question in the count.
  - If the previous end date was more recent than the current start date, then the overlap, including this start date, has already been included in the previous calculation.
    The MAX function within the DAYS function will have used this end date as the start date in the calculation of days.